# How to prevent AVPlayer pausing audio while buffering?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-audio, avplayer

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play live audio streamed from the Internet, but when it's buffering it pauses the audio, and then plays again.

How to prevent this pause while buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having to pause while playing, then the instantaneous bitrate of the streaming audio must be too high for the network connection you're testing with. Use a larger buffer, decrease the bitrate, or make the network connection better.

Comment: But I couldn't find in AVPlayer class a way to increase the buffering size. Any hints? Maybe playbackBufferFull?

Answer (score 3):

Winston,

One thing you could do use watch the [loadedTimeRanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/loadedTimeRanges) property on the current AVPlayerItem, as well as the [playbackLikelyToKeepUp](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/playbackLikelyToKeepUp), [duration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/duration), and [playbackBufferEmpty](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/playbackBufferEmpty) properties. Between those four, you should be able to work out some logic on how much of the track has buffered, and what your minimum buffering threshold should be to allow playback.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, Danny. I'll be looking into those options.